# Don't lock the computer when I press sleep

Tags: password, sleep, lock-screen

I have an automatic login and no screensaver password. I would easily have no password at all, but I am keeping it for the things that require root in hope of using alternative methods to get my convenience.

I removed the password from my keyring, because it does not get unlocked during the automatic login. I don't store anything in my keyring except some personal music and personal email anyway, also I am tech savvy and am more capable of protecting my computer than most.

The one place that still annoys me is when I put the computer to sleep and come back the next day, it asks for a password. I do this whenever I have a multi-day project I am working on (I am a programmer), so I don't have to launch all my windows back.

How can I have an automatic login when the computer wakes up from sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you are trying to disable the screen lock that occurs when resuming from a suspend, you can do:

sudo vi /etc/default/acpi-support

Find the line that begins with `LOCK_SCREEN=` and replace it with:

```
LOCK_SCREEN=false
```

You will have to reboot once. Then you can suspend and resume without a password prompt.

Comment: I am not allowed to write anything. How can I deal with this problem? Thx

Comment: didn't work for me, but the answer of Casper Li worked

Answer (score 2):

Here is a GUI method for turning off the lock function when you make your computer to sleep.

1. Search `lock`
   [image]
2. turn **OFF** the `Lock`.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy way to that just by configuration , (I think) it needs a custom event listener, to listen for sleeping and wakeup events. there is a project called [d-bus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org) is used to write your custom event listener, its C based but have alot of wrapper for popular languages. I hope that it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Ubuntu Tweak ( http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ ) allows to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

This command does right that:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

You can create a custom launcher with this command by right clicking on your desktop.

Comment: When doing this with Linux Mint (18.2 Sonya), I get `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'Suspend'`.